# Database id getting auto incremented

Tags: php, mysql, rest, module, prestashop

i have  **2 modules** created myself. each has its own **database**, these 2 modules are for product page. they have there own tabs in product page .. when i click on the **first module** tab in the product page . on the right hand side it shows a text field named **directory name** where i enter the directory name myself and i **save** it. This is properly getting saved in database with **id = 1** and **directory name = "directory name i typed"**  this is done for first module which i have created

for the **second module**. the right hand side contains the same fields , in the product page i select the **second module tab** .and on the **right hand side**. i enter the **directory name as i did for the first module**..this is getting saved in database with **id = 2** and **directory name = "directory name i typed for second module"**

the **problem is the id value of the first module is proper i.e is "1"** but for the **second module** when saved. this has its own **database table**. its getting **incremented to "2"**  for as i know the **id value should be the same for both the modules when saved once** ..but for the second module it s getting **incremented to "2"**

**Can any one tell me what is causing this problem**

**More info**: i,m using a hook to save  the data from the modules into the database .. hook is triggered when product page is updated. and also **the hook which is used in both the modules have same name**

Comment: My first suggestion would be to edit your question to be more readable and to make it clearer what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

My english is bad so I think its the reason why I understand your problem :D

First of all, I know it is not the good solution but what I would do to save time.

I would copy overrided product.php content with php function file_get_contents and extend this file with additional "extra field". Other thing, a few weeks ago, Prestashop noticed that now u can override module files! So other way - override first module files and add additional field. To my mind, this solution pretty good.

First module works without any problems and if second module installed it`s override your first module. After uninstall second module - you remove this module additional field.